# firestore query optional filters: Do I have to create an index for every possibility?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I undestand that I need an index for longer search querys in firestore. I am querying my docs like this:

```
  workoutFiter.tags.forEach(
    tag => (query = query.where(`tags.${tag.index}`, '==', true)),
  );
```

There are curretnly 5 tags in total, so do I have to create an index for every possible combination of tags? Because if so, I think I would have to have 120 (5 * 4 * 3 * 2) indexes. That seems a bit too overcomplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas), you can create only 200 composite indexes so this way might not be the best in case you want to add more tags and Firestore does not support a `array-contains-all` operator at the moment.

You can store an array of tags in the document and run a separate query for each tag using `array-contains` operator as shown below:

```
const q = query(colRef, where('tags', 'array-contains', 'tagName'));

// or "array-contains-any" to combine up to 10 array-contains clauses
```

If you need advanced filters, then checkout [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/filtering/how-to/filter-by-tags/#using-the-api) that supports the query that you are trying to perform and [Firebase Algolia Extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/algolia-firestore-algolia-search) to keep it updated.

Comment: I noticed there is an option to add Algolia in the firebase dashboard, but you have to upgrade to a payed plan. Can I use Angolia with a free plan if I add it from the Angolia website?

Comment: @JaRoMaster Yes, Algolia has a free tier so you can add data directly. The extension requires Cloud Functions to sync data between Firestore and Algolia so you in that case you need to upgrade but functions also have a decent free tier except some minor charges.

Comment: But as far as I understand, as soon as I activate the blaze plan, firebase charges me if I have to many databse calls etc, right?

Comment: If I use the Angolia free tier, do I need the blaze plan?

Comment: @JaRoMaster if you go over the free tier quota yes. You can setup alerts as well if you read a certain threshold. No, you don't need Blaze Plan on Firebase to use Algolia free tier, they are two different services.

Comment: Okay, I think I'll try the free playn first